# Getting Aspen and Gheat on Windows working

Tags: python, pygame, aspen

I am not really familiar Python setup, I am trying to get gheat running on a Windows box, and it tells me it can't find pygame.

I have tried Python25,26, older pygame version too.

I have installed those as well as numpy as it has a dependency.

Could someone with experience try and help me out getting it up and running.

I have tried running Process Monitor against it, and it seems to find all the files etc but aspen/gheat still tell me it can't find Pygame.

Links below.

1.) http://www.python.org/
2.) http://code.google.com/p/gheat/
3.) http://www.pygame.org/
4.) [Link](https://numpy.org/)

Cheers for any help.

Aside, It works fine on my ubuntu box just by install pygame and it works !

Comment: How have you installed pygame?
If you go to a python command line prompt and type "import pygame" does it works?

Comment: Yes to both, this is what confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to SeC- from the #csharp channel on Freenode, he figured out it is the problem with the latest trunk of aspen, (I thought I'd tried the older version)

http://www.zetadev.com/software/aspen/0.8/dist/aspen-0.8.zip

You will need the 0.8 version to get it working!!

Cheers anyway!